# loop or function to create new cols and fill based on lists

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I would like to write a function or loop that will create three new columns, then fill these columns with either the same value or a specified value, if the value in the original column is within one of three specified lists.

For example, here is what the data looks like:

```
> data
    a1   a2   a3
1    C    C    A
2    A B_20 B_20
3    A    C B_30
4    C    C B_40
5    C    A    A
6 B_60 B_60 B_60
7    A    A    C
8    A    C B_80
9 B_90    C B_90
```

I want to create three new columns (`a1_t`, `a2_t`, `a3_t`) where if `a1` is in `list1`

```
list1 <-c('B_10','B_20','B_30')
```

then fill in `a1_t`, with `B_00_30`

or if `a1` is in `list2`

```
list2 <-c('B_40','B_50','B_60')
```

then fill in `a1_t`, with `B_40_60`

or if `a1` is in `list3`

```
list3 <-c('B_70','B_80','B_90')
```

then fill in `a1_t`, with `B_70_90`

if not in `list1`, `list2`, or `list3`, then place the value from `a1` to `a1_t`.

Then iterate through this same procedure for `a2_t` and `a3_t` using `a2` and `a3` for matching.

In the end I would like the output to look like this:

```
> data
    a1   a2   a3    a1_t    a2_t    a3_t
1    A    A B_10       A       A B_00_30
2 B_20    A    C B_00_30       A       C
3 B_30    A    C B_00_30       A       C
4    C    C    A       C       C       A
5    A B_50 B_50       A B_40_60 B_40_60
6    C    C    A       C       C       A
7    C B_70    A       C B_70_90       A
8 B_80    C B_80 B_70_90       C B_70_90
9 B_90    C    A B_70_90       C       A
```

To create original raw data:

```
data <- structure(list(a1 = c("A", "B_20", "B_30", "C", "A", "C", "C", 
"B_80", "B_90"), a2 = c("A", "A", "A", "C", "B_50", "C", "B_70", 
"C", "C"), a3 = c("B_10", "C", "C", "A", "B_50", "A", "A", "B_80", 
"A")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

To create desired output data:

```
data <- structure(list(a1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B_20", "B_30", "B_80", "B_90", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                       a2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B_50", "B_70", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                       a3 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B_10", "B_50", "B_80", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                       a1_t = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B_00_30", "B_70_90", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                       a2_t = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B_40_60", "B_70_90", "C"), class = "factor"), 
                       a3_t = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B_00_30", "B_40_60", "B_70_90", "C"), class = "factor")), 
                  .Names = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a1_t", "a2_t", "a3_t"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Thanks
-al

Final working code w/ answer:

```
library(dplyr)
list1 <-c('B_10','B_20','B_30')
list2 <-c('B_40','B_50','B_60')
list3 <-c('B_70','B_80','B_90')

lookup = rbind(cbind(list = list1, val = "B_00_30"), 
               cbind(list2, "B_40_60"), 
               cbind(list3, "B_70_90"))
g <- sapply(data, function(x) { 
  tmp = lookup[, 2][match(x, lookup[, 1])] 
  ifelse(is.na(tmp), x, tmp) 
})
gd <- as.data.frame (g)
gd <- mutate (gd,a1_t=a1,a2_t=a2,a3_t=a3)
gd <- select (gd,a1_t,a2_t,a3_t)
h <- cbind (data,gd)
> h
    a1   a2   a3    a1_t    a2_t    a3_t
1    A    A B_10       A       A B_00_30
2 B_20    A    C B_00_30       A       C
3 B_30    A    C B_00_30       A       C
4    C    C    A       C       C       A
5    A B_50 B_50       A B_40_60 B_40_60
6    C    C    A       C       C       A
7    C B_70    A       C B_70_90       A
8 B_80    C B_80 B_70_90       C B_70_90
9 B_90    C    A B_70_90       C       A
```

Comment: Regarding the warning message, (I should have mentioned it, sorry) I was utilizing the property of `as.numeric` to make all non-numeric elements NA.  Of course, it turns on the warning.  You could use `suppressWarnings` or the updated script (in case you need it) to avoid warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way could be:

```
lookup = rbind(cbind(list = list1, val = "B_00_30"), 
               cbind(list2, "B_40_60"), 
               cbind(list3, "B_70_90"))
sapply(data, function(x) { 
                 tmp = lookup[, 2][match(x, lookup[, 1])] 
                 ifelse(is.na(tmp), x, tmp) 
             })
#      a1        a2        a3       
# [1,] "A"       "A"       "B_00_30"
# [2,] "B_00_30" "A"       "C"      
# [3,] "B_00_30" "A"       "C"      
# [4,] "C"       "C"       "A"      
# [5,] "A"       "B_40_60" "B_40_60"
# [6,] "C"       "C"       "A"      
# [7,] "C"       "B_70_90" "A"      
# [8,] "B_70_90" "C"       "B_70_90"
# [9,] "B_70_90" "C"       "A"
```

Then you can `cbind` to "data" and coerce to "data.frame" as needed.

Comment: For the `lookup`, you could also do `melt(setNames(list(list1, list2, list3), c("B_00_30", "B_40_60", "B_70-90")))`

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz, this worked fine and didn't produce any warning messages as it did when I ran akrun's code. I've edited my question to include renaming columns, coercing cols and cbinding.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `cut`

```
 indx <- cut(as.numeric(gsub(".\\_","",as.matrix(data))),breaks=c(0,30,60,90),labels=F)
```

(Here, you will get a warning message because `as.numeric` on those elements that are characters will coerce them to NAs, which was my intention.)

or using info from `list1:list3`

```
 val <- sapply(mget(ls(pattern="list")),function(x) max(as.numeric(gsub("._","",x))))
  val
 # list1 list2 list3 
 # 30    60    90 

 #indx <- cut(as.numeric(gsub(".\\_","",as.matrix(data))),breaks=c(0,val),labels=F)  
 indx[!is.na(indx)] <- c("B_00_30","B_40_60", "B_70_90")[indx[!is.na(indx)]]
 indx[is.na(indx)] <- unlist(data)[!grepl("_", unlist(data))]

  data1 <- data
 data1[] <- indx
 colnames(data1) <- paste(colnames(data1),"t",sep="_")
```

#### Update

To avoid the warning message, you could do:

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(data)
indx <- grepl("\\d",gsub(".\\_","",m1))
indx1 <- cut(as.numeric(gsub(".\\_","",m1[indx])),breaks=c(0,30,60,90),labels=F) 
m1[indx] <- c("B_00_30", "B_40_60", "B_70_90")[indx1]
data1 <- data
data1[] <- m1
colnames(data1) <- paste(colnames(data1),"t",sep="_")
 cbind(data, data1)
 #       a1   a2   a3    a1_t    a2_t    a3_t
 #  1    A    A B_10       A       A B_00_30
 #  2 B_20    A    C B_00_30       A       C
 #  3 B_30    A    C B_00_30       A       C
 #  4    C    C    A       C       C       A
 #  5    A B_50 B_50       A B_40_60 B_40_60
 #  6    C    C    A       C       C       A
 #  7    C B_70    A       C B_70_90       A
 #  8 B_80    C B_80 B_70_90       C B_70_90
 #  9 B_90    C    A B_70_90       C       A
```